# Cmd Enter keyup combination detection using javascript

Tags: javascript, onkeyup, keyup

I'm using a keyup detection into all my forms to detect the enter button. 
This is easy, when you are focused in a form's input if you hit enter and the event keyCode is equal to 13 then the form submitted.

But now I want to detect the Cmd + Enter combination, because when you are focused in a textarea, the enter button is a line break. So how my detect statement should look like?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean <kbd>ctrl</kbd> with `Cmd`? Then check if `event.ctrlKey` is true:

```
if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 13) {
    alert('now');
}
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/sxRDw/).

P.s: there are also the booleans `event.altKey` for <kbd>alt</kbd>, `event.shiftKey` for <kbd>shift</kbd> and `event.metakey`

Comment: Thank you very much @scessor, but I'm looking for ⌘ button, not the Ctrl... Any thoughts?

Comment: Cmd is the same as evet.metaKey @AndrewCkor