# Phone Number TextBox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have three `Textboxes` for Phones numbers. `Textbox1 max length is 3` , `2nd's max length is 3` and `3rd max length is 4`. When user types `three digits` in `TextBox1` the `cursor moves` automatically to `TextBox2` same thing happens with `TextBox2` as well as TextBox3. I am handling this functionality in `keyup` event.

[image]

Issue is, when I press

<kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>

<kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

<kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>

the cursor moves automatically to `Textbox3` because `Textbox` reaches it's `Max Length` and navigates it to next `Textbox`. I want to keep it on `TextBox1`. Any Ideas?

### My code is below.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbPh2" MaxLength="3" onkeyup="Mainautotab2(this, 0, event);"/>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbPh22" MaxLength="3" onkeyup="Mainautotab2(this, 1, event);"/>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbPh222" class="midium" MaxLength="4" />


function Mainautotab2(original, destination, evt) {
         if (document.getElementById('<%= tbPh2.ClientID%>').value.length == 3 && document.getElementById('<%= tbPh22.ClientID%>').value.length == 3) {

         if (destination == 0)
             document.getElementById("<%=tbPh22.ClientID %>").focus();
         if (destination == 1)
             document.getElementById("<%=tbPh222.ClientID %>").focus();
     }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you check text length?

Comment: @Jcl Max Length is coming from text length.

Comment: I suggesting adding your keyup event code too

Comment: @Guest , if when copying and pasting the text in the textbox reaches its maxlength, then the cursor should move to the next textbox. That is correct behaviour. Please edit and add your keyup code so we can actually see what's wrong, we are only guessing otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend checking for the use of the control key being pressed, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364338/cmd-enter-keyup-combination-detection-using-javascript) for more information on how to do that. If you detect the CTRL key is pressed then do not move to the next textbox.

Alternatively, if you only want the "move to next" feature to work as the user is typing the 3rd character then perhaps something along the lines of checking the character count on keydown. Make sure that this new key press in the 3rd character and the previous keypress was the second character (i.e. store lastKeyPressCount somewhere)

---

As I am such a nice guy! here is some of my own work:

Html

```
<input type="text" id="1" maxlength="3" data-nextid="2"/>
<input type="text" id="2" maxlength="3" data-nextid="3"/>
<input type="text" id="3" maxlength="4"/>​
```

JavaScript (w/JQuery)

```
$("input").keyup(function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey || e.which == 17 || e.which == 65 || e.which == 67 || e.which == 86){
        return;        
    }
    if($(this).val().length == $(this).attr("maxlength")){
        var nextid = $(this).data("nextid");
        if(nextid){
              $("#" + nextid).focus();       
        }
    }
});​
```

Keep in mind that this code has been specifically set to ignore the CTRL key in addition to the letters A, C and V.

[See here for a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/qsq3t/3/)

Comment: +1 too, although I "fixed" Guest's solution, this should be the way to go.

Comment: @musefan This is the same situation as told in query. Try pressing the Ctrl + A it will move to next `TextBox` in case Max Length is 3.

Comment: **-1 Not working. This is the same as mentioned in query. Check your JsFiddle.**

Comment: @abcdefghi - Yes, press three chars in Textbox 1. Press Ctrl + A. This will move the cursor to 3rd TextBox.

Comment: @Guest: it works if you ensure you are holding ctrl when you release the other button (A, C or V)... you could modify it so it ignore those letters too (bearing in mind these a number only fields that should be fine)

Comment: @musefan, can you keep the last JsFiddle only reference only? because this part is merly useful for those whose are searching for same issue and I will accept

Comment: @Guest: I have made some changes to the answer

Comment: This is very useful. +1 and accepted. Hope it will be useful for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use OnKeyUp event. Use TextValueChanged of the textbox and count the length of the text in the textbox